# Deal with Ties when Using Index/Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently pulling the top (5) number of numerical values from one sheet and inputting them into a different sheet. Each number is within its own column and there is a name matching that column, EX:

[image]

And so, having a tie is common with the data that I'm working with, so it nearly deprecates my formulas.

For getting the name:

```
=INDEX('Total Cases by Categories'!$B$18:$B$50, MATCH(LARGE('Total Cases by Categories'!$H$18:$H$50, A39),'Total Cases by Categories'!$H$18:$H$50, 0))
```

For getting the numerical value associated with the name:

```
=LARGE('Total Cases by Categories'!$H$18:$H, A39)
```

And so, when there are 2 people with the same numerical value associated within a category, then that person appears twice, I assume because of their position within the sheet.

So something like this happens:
[image]

So in the event of a tie, I would want to list both names that have the same amount of points instead of the first name that shows up with the duplicated value.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Comment: i'm using google sheets

Comment: Then you can easily use `FILTER()` formula with `LARGE()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, LARGE will give you both of tied names. It's MATCH that can't look beyond the first. To the best of my knowledge there is no way around that (the difficult one being not to use MATCH). Therefore the solution is to have no ties.

This is achieved with helper columns that contain no identical numbers. This can be achieved by adding an insignificant decimal. Since you are dealing with integers, adding 0.1 would be insignificant for your purposes but 13.1 is different from 13.2. If you need to extract the "real" number from this use INT(13.2).

Using the row number to generate an insignificant decimal is popular for this purpose. In row 1 *ROW()/10* will return 0.1. But in row 10 *ROW()/10* will return 1.0 which isn't an insignificant number anymore. Therefore you have to work with *ROW()/100* or an even larger divisor, depending upon how many rows you have. Try *ROW()/10^6* - any decimal will do the tie-breaking job.

You may not like that using ROW() will list tied participants in the order in which they appear in the worksheet. The differentiating decimals can be created by any other means that doesn't create ties in itself.

Normally, the helper columns with the decimals added will be hidden. They contain a formula like `=D23 + (ROW()/10000)` which manages itself. You can then use that column for the MATCH function to list all participants in the order of LARGE using the helper column or the original. Just make sure that MATCH refers to the helper column.

Comment: So would my equation look something like this (say match is column m)

=INDEX('Total Cases by Categories'!$B$18:$B$50, MATCH(LARGE('Total Cases by Categories'!$M$18:$M$50, A39),'Total Cases by Categories'!$H$18:$H$50, 0))

Comment: Yes, this looks about right, if the unique values are in column M. However the transparency of your formula could be improved, as well as the formula shortened, by using named ranges: =INDEX(Scores, MATCH(LARGE(OFFSET(Scores,0,11), A39), where `Scores` = B18:B50. If you don't like to use the Offset function (slows down the sheet if you have too many of them, declare a second range, like `UniqScores`.